# compare between two file.c and count the number of function that have been added or deleted from those files using c#

Tags: c#

I'm using c# to compare between two files.c and I can find out if they are different or not but I'm looking for a way to count the number of function (method) that have been add or deleted or modified into those file.c

Here 's my code until now

```
private bool FileCompare(string file1, string file2)
{
     int file1byte;
     int file2byte;
     FileStream fs1;
     FileStream fs2;

     // Determine if the same file was referenced two times.
     if (file1 == file2)
     {
          // Return true to indicate that the files are the same.
          return true;
     }

     // Open the two files.
     fs1 = new FileStream(file1, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
     fs2 = new FileStream(file2, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

     // Check the file sizes. If they are not the same, the files 
        // are not the same.
     if (fs1.Length != fs2.Length)
     {
          // Close the file
          fs1.Close();
          fs2.Close();

          // Return false to indicate files are different
return false;
     }
```

anyone has any sugggetion?
thanks for help.

Comment: so you want from us to write a `C` parser for you ?

Comment: @Selman22 - or suggest a `C` parser

Comment: Something useful in the answer(s)?

Answer (score 0):

*First of all: You have a horrible spelling and grammar!*

The ways you can go are to write an own C parser or using an existing one, which provides your needed information.

Check this tool: [cpp-ripper](https://code.google.com/p/cpp-ripper/):

> The goal of the C++ Ripper project is to create a simple and reusable
>   parsing framework specialized for C and C++ code. The C++ Ripper
>   parser is a recursive descent parser, which uses operator overloading
>   to allow the expression of grammars using a notation similar to PEGs.
>
> I am developing C++ Ripper to the form the basis for tools that parse
>   C++ documentation, perform pretty printing, and that can be used to
>   refactor code. It should be easy to adapt for other purposes and other
>   languages.

You can get its source from [here](https://code.google.com/p/cpp-ripper/source/checkout).

If it doesn't provide you all information you need, read the sources, whose let you inspire to write your own parser/framework.